# Getting file as logged in user

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I wanted to ask if the follow is possible in PHP. Let's say there is a file on my google drive with the ID '123-abc', would it be possible to fetch it as if I was logged in to my account, without using the API? 
Let's say I'm trying to download a file from 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=123-abc', is there a way to tell the website i'm signed in by logging in with PHP? I also don't want to make the file public.

Comment: Is it necessary for the file to be on google drive?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do it with google drive, is that an issue?

Comment: Haven't you found any help from [Google API DOC](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) ? it seems you can access files, but not directly (I have *not* read it completely though ^^). Have you some code yet ?

Comment: I have looked through the API, although would prefer not to use it. I haven't got any code, sorry. I'm specifically trying to use it for 'https://docs.google.com/get_video_info', which doesn't, i believe, have an API, if It did I wouldn't mind using it.

Comment: @GhostCyborg : you need to access *your* file, containing some private data, then want to fetch through that data in order to use it on your site ?

Comment: If you want to use google drive, then here is no way else using the API, because you have to be logged in to a google account even to view the file so how about downloading it, no, i thing there is no way else the API. Anyway, please share with us what is the final result of your researches for this question.

Comment: @OldPadawan Yes, that sums it up

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily Then, would it be possible for the server running the script to be logged into an account which would have access to the file?

Comment: @GhostCyborg : IMHO, no way google let you access *any* drive without their own API and a personnal encypted KEY /quit Cap'tain Obvious mode ^^

Comment: @OldPadawan I guess that's true.

Comment: But can I ask, what's the reason you don't want to use the API, the whole point of google creating its APIs is just to make it easier for the developrs.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily I said it in a previous comment, but I didn't want to use the API since https://docs.google.com/get_video_info , doesn't have an api, if it did, I would've used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource for the available video metadata. Specifically:-

> videoMediaMetadata    object  Additional metadata about video media. This
> may not be available immediately upon upload.
>
> videoMediaMetadata.width  integer The width of the video in pixels.
>
> videoMediaMetadata.height integer The height of the video in pixels.
>
> videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis long    The duration of the video in
> milliseconds.

I suggest you use the "try it now" facility of https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get to get a file and see if the vailable meta data is what you are looking for.